# What is the easiest way to store List<object> in Room Database?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm learning Android Programming as a beginner. I'm trying to do something like this:

```java
@Entity(table_name = "family_table")
class Human {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    //Here is my problem
    private List<Human> children = new ArrayList<Human> ();

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void haveChildren(String name, int age) {
        children.add(new Human(name,age));
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDescription() {
        return age;
    }

    public int totalChildren() {
        return children.size();
    }

}
```

Later from main class I want to use this Class. For example:

```java
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human person1 = new Human("Alex",32);

        person1.haveChildren("Jhon",6);
        person1.haveChildren("Abraham",3);

        System.out.println(person1.totalChildren());


    }
}
```

Room provides methods to store data such as int, Boolean, String etc., but I can't store custom Objects inside Room entries. It says:
`Cannot figure out how to save this field into database.You can consider adding a type converter for it`.

I've searched internet for the solution. Whatever I learnt, there is mainly two type of solution.

1. [TypeConverting](https://mobikul.com/insert-custom-list-and-get-that-list-in-room-database-using-typeconverter/)
2. [Using @foreignKeys](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a)

These two methods helps to understand the process. But the **problem for 1st solution** is, each time I create a new child object(which is stored in `List<Human> children` variable) I've to convert this `List<object>` to a JSON format(for solution 1) and if I want to get the data back I've to convert it again to the `List<object>`. Through this is a solution, it seems to be very inefficient for large `List<object>`.

For solution 2, since I'm referencing the same type of Object, why should I create another table(entity) for it?  **Can't I use the same Entity(`family_table` for my example)?**

**If I must have to create another entity the how can I do so?** (The tutorial in solution 2 is confusing to me as a beginner).

**Does there any other solution present in such situation?**

Comment: For solution 1 (conversion into json and backwards) you may use already existing solutions. Since you asked in the context of database, I can suggest to use mongodb. You may store arbitrary fields (See noSQL).

Here is a tutorial which you may find beneficial: https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/java-mapping-pojos

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion and tutorial link. As I am familiar with Room, it would be easy for me to work with this for now. Does converting a large size of List<object> to Json and vice versa affect performane?

Comment: it depends on size of your object as well. But in short, of course it will affect the time it needs to de/serialize. If performance is important, you may do serialization of different Rooms in parallel or using more faster serializers in general. I remember jackson used to be the fastest, you can find benchmark tests online to compare.

Comment: One more problem,  when I'd like to create an child object of a child class for example when Jhon will grow up and we'd like to create an child object for him, then JSON operation is useless.

Comment: You have have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

Comment: @philoopher97 I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you maybe give example?